# R data.table - How to explode a nested array?

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to explode a column containing a string which is a nested array.

```
require(data.table)

# Starting dataframe
df = structure(list(col = "[{a1=1, b1=2, c1=ABC, e1=[{f1=12}]}, {a2=5, b2=3, c2=DEF, e2=[{f2=15}]}]", 
    group = 1), .Names = c("col", "group"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L))
df
                                                                      col group
1: [{a1=1, b1=2, c1=ABC, e1=[{f1=12}]}, {a2=5, b2=3, c2=DEF, e2=[{f2=15}]}     1

# result expected
                                 col group
1: {a1=1, b1=2, c1=ABC, e1=[{f1=12]}     1
2: {a2=5, b2=3, c2=DEF, e2=[{f2=15]}     1
```

I have tried a few things (str_locate, etc), but nothing works as I wish.
Can someone help?

Comment: `class(df$col)` is "character" so it just "looks" nested array but in reality it's just a string.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for your data:

```
> df[, .(col = strsplit(gsub('^\\[|\\]$', '', col), '(?<=}), ', perl = T)[[1]]), by = .(group)]
#    group                                col
# 1:     1 {a1=1, b1=2, c1=ABC, e1=[{f1=12}]}
# 2:     1 {a2=5, b2=3, c2=DEF, e2=[{f2=15}]}
```

This solution is not robust and could fail in more complex cases such as `e1=[{f1=12}, {f2=23}]` though.

Answer (score 0):

A little clumsy but step by step seems to work at least.

```
s1 <- sub("\\[\\{", "\\{", df$col)
s2 <- unlist(strsplit(s1, "\\}, \\{", perl=TRUE))
s2[2] <- sub("\\}\\]\\}\\]", "\\}\\]\\}", s2[2])
s2[1] <- paste0(s2[1], "}", collapse="")
s2[2] <- paste0("{", s2[2], collapse="")


> data.table(col=s2, group=df$group)
                                  col group
1: {a1=1, b1=2, c1=ABC, e1=[{f1=12}]}     1
2: {a2=5, b2=3, c2=DEF, e2=[{f2=15}]}     1
```